Getting Unknown method error in visualforce page, even though the method present in controller
Method
public Boolean getGeneralInsurance(){
    If(theCase.customer__c == 'yes'{
        IsCustomer =true;
    }else{
        IsCustomer= false;
    }
    return IsCustomer;
}

<apex:actionFunction name="Dopanel" action="{!GeneralInsurance}" rerender="dobFied" oncomplete="handleChange();"/> 


Your code hasn't compiled, because you're missing a parentheses in the if statement:
public Boolean getGeneralInsurance(){
                            //  ⬇️ Missing )
    If(case.customer__c == 'yes') {
        IsCustomer =true;
    }
    return IsCustomer;
}

It's also really not necessary to have an if statement here:
public Boolean getGeneralInsurance(){
    return IsCustomer = case.Customer__c == 'yes';
}

I'm not sure if you need IsCustomer in this case, but I've left it in.

@PavanKumarH You can edit your question to include the additional code. Also, if you have an error message, please share it so we can better help you.
